# Attempting to place JDIalog on top of current position of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm writing an extension to a Java application; its API does not have access to the position of the main window of the application. I create my own JFrame, and it positions that JFrame with

```
AwtUtil.centerWindow(jFrameReference);
```

I would *like* to position the JFrame on top of the current position of the main window, but without any reference to the main window, I'm assuming I cannot do that. The above call appears to put the JFrame in the center of the #1 display on my Windows 10 machine.

But I also create a JDialog to be popped up with a button, and I would like to position that on top of my own JFrame, wherever it is when the button is clicked. To do this, I put a reference to the JFrame in the constructor for the dialog, and then in the dialog constructor call:

```
super(jFrameReference, title, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODEL);
```

But if I move the JFrame, then click the button to pop up the dialog, the dialog appears where the JFrame first appeared, not where the JFrame is when the button is clicked. Is the position of the JFrame somehow saved when the dialog is created (which is before it is displayed)? What am I missing here?

Comment: If you don’t have a reference to the main window, you may still [get all frames](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames()) and see whether you can recognize it. Besides that, I don’t understand your second question. Do you expect an existing dialog to change its position *after* it has been created?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. No, I do the action that displays the JFrame, move the JFrame, then display the JDialog, and the JDialog appears where the JFrame was originally; I want the JDialog to appear on top of the JFrame wherever the JFrame is when I create the JDialog.

Comment: From looking through the code of `JDialog`, as far as I can tell, it makes no reference to the owner window when begin made visible.  In fact if you walk through the `JOptionPane` workflow, it will set the location of the dialog relative to the parent component itself, so to answer your question - no, there is no "magic" going on that will place the dialog on top of the window by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a general answer, but it fixed my problem. My JDialog was created without being made visible when the JFrame was in its original position. I guess the position of the JFrame is somehow saved somewhere and used when the JDialog is displayed. I fixed the problem by storing a reference to the JFrame as a private variable in the dialog, then `calling jDialogReference.setLocationRelativeTo(jFrameReference)` at the time the dialog is made visible.

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re trying to mystify the situation (“is somehow saved somewhere”). The `JDialog` is an object and its position is part of this object. After you created it, it has a position. There is nothing surprising in the fact that when you make it visible at a later time, it still has the same position.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to store the frame in another private variable when you specified it to the dialog’s constructor as the dialog’s owner. You can [query the owner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#getOwner()) at any time.

Comment: The question is whether the position of the frame is obtained when the dialog is created, or when the dialog is displayed. I was assuming the latter; I didn't see why the dialog's position would be established before it was shown. Now I know.

Comment: `jDialogReference.setLocationRelativeTo(jDialogReference.getOwner())` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: Well, you can close and re-open dialogs while keeping the position, so it should be clear that opening a dialog is not supposed to change the position. That’s straight-forward API design. It’s easy to provide a method for “change location now” but practically impossible to create a reasonable API that requires the programmer to take actions to mandate no change, every time no change is intended.

Comment: I suppose I should have said "when the dialog is *first* displayed". When setVisible() or its equivalent is *first* called, I was expecting the dialog to show up on top of its parent. Of course after that it's supposed to show up wherever it was last time.